# Scalaz-stream chunking UP to N

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

Given a queue like so:

```
val queue: Queue[Int] = async.boundedQueue[Int](1000)
```

I want to pull off this queue and stream it into a downstream Sink, in chunks of UP to 100.

```
queue.dequeue.chunk(100).to(downstreamConsumer)
```

works sort of, but it will not empty the queue if I have say 101 messages. There will be 1 message left over, unless another 99 are pushed in. I want to take as many as I can off the queue up to 100, as fast as my downstream process can handle.

Is there an existing combinator available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this a different way then I had intended.

The scalaz-stream queue now contains a `dequeueBatch` method that allows dequeuing all values in the queue, up to N, or blocks.

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/issues/338

Answer (score 0):

For this, you may need to monitor size of the queue when dequeueing from it. then, if the size reaches 0 you simply won't wait to any more elements. In fact you may implement `elastic` sizing of the batching based on the size of queue. I.e. :

```
val q = async.unboundedQueue[String]

val deq:Process[Task,(String,Int)] = q.dequeue zip q.size
val elasticChunk: Process1[(String,Int), Vector[String]] = ???
val downstreamConsumer : Sink[Task,Vector[String]] = ???

deq.pipe(elasticChunk) to downstreamConsumer
```

Comment: How would you implement elasticChunk?

Comment: I actually solved this using the handy q.dequeueBatch method. Didn't know it existed.